# Intel xdk daemon with intel galileo gen2

Tags: javascript, linux, intel-xdk, intel-galileo

I  am trying working on Intel Galileo Gen 2 with Intel XDK and successfully connected galileo gen 2  with XDK manually over ethernet as its not detecting board, i have installed bonjour also.

I have also created new project without any error but when I am uploading the code its showing error that daemon is old please install least version 0.1.3. When i am trying to upgrade its showing another error I have attached the snapshot of the error.

I have tried all the methods like restarting the system board, uninstalling the XDK IoT edition and installed new XDK 3641.

I have updated other libraries and restarted the daemon but getting same error.

I have tried checking whether daemon is working or not and found no error.

Only one error i am getting couldn't update daemon

> Error: TypeError: Invalid Version: 4.x.x

I am also unable to install Intel system studio following all the steps as mentioned on guide at Intel website. It showing error of

> Can't create/start docker machine: Running pre-create checks...
>
> Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v
>   enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"
>
> finished with error 3.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding use of your Galileo with the XDK, try downloading and installing version 3759 at http://xdk.intel.com. This is a new update (yesterday) that includes some code to specifically address updating the XDK daemon on IoT target boards. Please let me know if it works.

BTW -- no need to uninstall/reinstall the XDK if this fails. If it fails it is likely something to do with the version of Linux on the Galileo, the network connection or the XDK itself. If it does fail, please report the issue on our forum at https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk